# Upgrading Client version via msi

Tags: batch-file, windows-installer

I have a client version of a software called KRONOS and i need to update this via a batch file that will run a MSI.  First I need to check to see if the application is installed.  If it is, I need to see what version it is to see if I need to uninstall prior to installing the new version.  I was thinking of using something to check the Registry DisplayVersion but not sure how todo the compare within the BAT file.
The version that is installed is 3.64 but I need to upgrade to 3.611.
I was hoping to do this upon logon based on a certain date and certain users since not all users have this software BUT if a user logs on to a pc, the software gets installed, I still want it to get installed on another pc if the same user goes there.
Does anybody have something like this
Thanks in advance

Comment: in a batch file you won't be able to access the registry.  Can you make use of vbscripts, or do you have an aggressive anti-virus that might block it?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an MSI that will do the upgrade for you by uninstall the product if it is installed, this way you will basically only need to run the MSI and it will take care for everything.

You need to specify how you create the MSI in order to configure it to support upgrades.